# Laravel google maps check if rectangle contains location

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to do like this google maps documentation example [containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation#maps_poly_containsLocation-typescript) in Laravel, I have an area with selected points like a rectangle(polygon) and I want to check if a new point is inside or outside this area.

I tried [this package](https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-maps#containsLocation) and used the function below but to no avail.

```
        $response = \GoogleMaps::load('directions')
        ->setParam([
            'origin'          => 'place_id:ChIJ685WIFYViEgRHlHvBbiD5nE',
            'destination'     => 'place_id:ChIJA01I-8YVhkgRGJb0fW4UX7Y',
        ])
        ->setParam([
            'origin'          => 'place_id:ChIJA01I-8YVhkgRGJb0fW4UX7Y',
            'destination'     => 'place_id:ChIJIyaYpQC4h0gRJxfnfHsU8mQ',
        ])
        ->setParam([
            'origin'          => 'place_id:ChIJIyaYpQC4h0gRJxfnfHsU8mQ',
            'destination'     => 'place_id:ChIJ685WIFYViEgRHlHvBbiD5nE',
        ])

        ->containsLocation(56.152257678858895, -3.6390740222681406);
```

Comment: What does "to no avail" mean? Is the response wrong, does it throw an exception? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @VitorHugoSchwaab I didn't get any true response, it feels like the package's containsLocation() function is referring only to the point in the direction, not inside the polygon! even though I'm not sure because all responses are false;

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this can be done without google maps, just pure php to do some calculations, thanks to [tutorialspots.com/php-detect-point-in-polygon](http://tutorialspots.com/php-detect-point-in-polygon-506.html).

PHP function to detect Point in Polygon:

```
function contains($point, $polygon)
{
    if($polygon[0] != $polygon[count($polygon)-1])
        $polygon[count($polygon)] = $polygon[0];
    $j = 0;
    $oddNodes = false;
    $x = $point[1];
    $y = $point[0];
    $n = count($polygon);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        $j++;
        if ($j == $n)
        {
            $j = 0;
        }
        if ((($polygon[$i][0] < $y) && ($polygon[$j][0] >= $y)) || (($polygon[$j][0] < $y) && ($polygon[$i][0] >=
            $y)))
        {
            if ($polygon[$i][1] + ($y - $polygon[$i][0]) / ($polygon[$j][0] - $polygon[$i][0]) * ($polygon[$j][1] -
                $polygon[$i][1]) < $x)
            {
                $oddNodes = !$oddNodes;
            }
        }
    }
    return $oddNodes;
}
```

To test:

```
$polygon = array(
    array(0,0),
    array(0,5),
    array(4,3),
    array(3,0),
    array(0,0),
);
 
$point1 = array(3,3);
 
echo contains($point1,$polygon)?'IN':'OUT';
echo "<br />";
 
$point2 = array(4,4);
 
echo contains($point2,$polygon)?'IN':'OUT';
```

> Result:
> IN, OUT